# Extracting info from logger. (Creating a BitMEX bot)

Tags: python

Thank you for your time.  I am creating a BitMEX trading bot. I downloaded a bot scaffold from here:  https://github.com/BitMEX/sample-market-maker

I am currently trying to get info of my recent trades so I can amend future ones.  The only way I can see doing this using the provided API is by getting information directly from the logger.  When a trade is executed, the logger returns this info from the ws.thread :

```
                    if table == 'order':
                        is_canceled = 'ordStatus' in updateData and updateData['ordStatus'] == 'Canceled'
                        if 'cumQty' in updateData and not is_canceled:
                            contExecuted = updateData['cumQty'] - item['cumQty']
                            if contExecuted > 0:
                                instrument = self.get_instrument(item['symbol'])
                                self.logger.info("Execution: %s %d Contracts of %s at %.*f" %
                                         (item['side'], contExecuted, item['symbol'],
                                          instrument['tickLog'], item['price']))
```

Is there any way I can extract the quantity and price so I can use it as variables for a different function?

I suppose what I'm looking for is some type of function where

if the logger is executed, then label contExecuted and item['price'] and extract it to a variable.